# Java task not updating jlabel

Tags: java

Question I have is I am trying to update my gui with a timer(this works and changes the image for mypic but, it will not update mytext label for some weird reason any help would be very much appreciated!

*I should add that mytext isn't showing up at all on my gui since introducing the timer...but mypic does????

```
package widget;

import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder;
import javafx.geometry.HorizontalDirection;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import widget.weather;

import static java.awt.Color.*;

/**
 * Created by xxxxxxzz on 10/19/2016.
 */
public class Widget extends JFrame {

    String icon_image = null;
    String temp = null;
    JLabel myText = null;
    JLabel mypic = null;


    Timer SimpleTimer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                icon_image = weather.weather_pic();
                temp = weather.temp();
                URL url = new URL(icon_image);
                ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);

                myText = new JLabel(temp);
                //Tried setting it like this and still doesn't work
                // myText = new JLabel("HOT");

                mypic = new JLabel();

                myText.setText(temp);
                mypic.setIcon(img);



            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    public Widget() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        setUndecorated(true);

        setSize(150,150);


        temp = weather.temp();
        icon_image = weather.weather_pic();



        URL url = new URL(icon_image);



        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);
        myText = new JLabel(temp);
        mypic = new JLabel();

        myText.setText(temp);
        mypic.setIcon(img);

        myText.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);


        mypic.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);


        add(myText);
        add(mypic);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0,0,150,150);
        AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(this, shape);
        SimpleTimer.start();
    }





    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, URISyntaxException {
        new Widget();
    }


}
```

## UPDATE with suggestions still isn't working..

```
package widget;

import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder;
import javafx.geometry.HorizontalDirection;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import widget.weather;

import static java.awt.Color.*;

/**
 * Created by jsnow on 10/19/2016.
 */
public class Widget extends JFrame {

    String icon_image = null;
    String temp = null;
    JLabel myText = new JLabel();
    JLabel mypic = new JLabel();


    Timer SimpleTimer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                icon_image = weather.weather_pic();
                temp = weather.temp();
                URL url = new URL(icon_image);
                ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);


                myText.setText(temp);
                mypic.setIcon(img);



            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    public Widget() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        setUndecorated(true);

        setSize(150,150);


        temp = weather.temp();
        icon_image = weather.weather_pic();



        URL url = new URL(icon_image);



        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);


        myText.setText(temp);
        mypic.setIcon(img);

        myText.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);


        mypic.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);


        add(myText);
        add(mypic);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0,0,150,150);
        AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(this, shape);
        SimpleTimer.start();
    }





    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, URISyntaxException {
        new Widget();
    }


}
```

Comment: don´t reinitialize the `JLabel`, just set the new text / image.

Comment: Just do `myText.setText(temp)` rather than creating a new `JLabel` each time.

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestion @d.j.brown still no luck

Comment: So  you have double checkedd that temp is changing and isnt just null?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution which you can tailor to your use. The cause seemed to be the way you had tried to display the Components rather than the code in your action listener.

Your approach was just replacing `myText` with `myPic` when you initially set up the `JFrame`. Instead you need to use a layout manager. The example I've given is with overlaying using `JLayeredPane`. You may wish to use a layout manager instead if this is not the desired outcome, see the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html) on using layout managers.

**Widget class**

```
package widget;

import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Widget extends JFrame {

    private static final int UPDATE_TICK = 5_000;
    private static final int WIDGET_WIDTH = 150;
    private static final int WIDGET_HEIGHT = 150;

    private JLabel myText = new JLabel();
    private JLabel myPic = new JLabel();
    private Weather weather = new Weather();
    private Timer simpleTimer;

    public void createAndShow() {
        setUndecorated(true);
        setSize(WIDGET_WIDTH, WIDGET_HEIGHT);
        Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, WIDGET_WIDTH, WIDGET_HEIGHT);
        // AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(this, shape);
        setShape(shape); // do this instead


        myText.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        myPic.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        JLayeredPane layered = new JLayeredPane();
        myText.setBounds(0, 0, WIDGET_WIDTH, WIDGET_HEIGHT);
        myPic.setBounds(0, 0, WIDGET_WIDTH, WIDGET_HEIGHT);
        layered.add(myPic, 1, 0);
        layered.add(myText, 2, 0);
        add(layered);

        simpleTimer = new Timer(UPDATE_TICK, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                update();
            }
        });

        update();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        simpleTimer.start();
    }

    private void update() {        
        myText.setText(weather.getTemp());
        myPic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(weather.getImage(WIDGET_WIDTH, WIDGET_HEIGHT)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Widget w = new Widget();
                w.createAndShow();;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Weather class for demonstration purposes**

```
package widget;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

public class Weather {

    private static final Random rand = new Random();
    private static final Color[] randColors = {Color.YELLOW,
        Color.GREEN,
        Color.WHITE};

    public String getTemp() {
        return Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(100));
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage(int width, int height) {
        int colorIndex = rand.nextInt(randColors.length);
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
                img.setRGB(x, y, randColors[colorIndex].getRGB());
            }
        }
        return img;
    }
}
```